# How to pass string value in jquery checkbox onclick event

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, checkbox

I am having checkbox in column header and onclick sending event argument as checkbox and name of column where checkbox is belong to:

```
"aoColumns": [
{ 'mData': '@ModelName.ColumnDateTime',
  'sName': '@ModelName.ColumnDateTime',
  'sTitle': '<input type="checkbox" onclick="handleClick(this, @ModelName.ColumnDateTime)" id="checkbox1"></input> DateTimeColumn',},
{ 'mData': '@ModelName.ColumnSource', 'sTitle': '@ModelName.ColumnSource <input type="checkbox"></input>', 'bSortable': false }],

function handleClick(cb, sName) 
{
    alert("Clicked, new value = " + cb.checked + sName);
}
```

I am getting error for `@ModelName.ColumnDateTime` for `handleClick(this, @ModelName.ColumnDateTime)`, value for `@ModelName.ColumnDateTime` is DateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quote your string

```
onclick="handleClick(this, \'@ModelName.ColumnDateTime\')"
```

Comment: Error `Expected }`

Comment: sorry bro, I am beginner in jquery!